# wso2 IS carbon, throws error in User profile page , after adding a user claim in claim management

Tags: java, apache-axis, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have created a tenant and configured a user-store with read only ldap. After that i am able to view user list and user profile pages successfully. And I  added an extra claim called 'employee ID' through claim management. Now i am not able to view the user profile page. It throws an exception

Error Log

```
[2015-12-10 20:39:47,287] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.profile.ui.client.UserProfileCient} -  org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[1,1203]
Message: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x1b) was found in the element content of the document.
```

I hope some XML data is corrupted during save operation.

[image]

Need help to resolve this issue

Thanks

Comment: can you remove the newly added claim and check if that works?

Comment: I have tired removing that particular claim also. Same system error get thrown. @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne

Comment: I tried the same steps to reproduce but it i could not. Could you please state whether you add read only ldap user store as primary or secondary.   Also, have you mapped the target for new claim properly to exiting claim attribute on ldap.

Comment: Have you made any changes to the user store after creating the claim? If so please double check the <IS_HOME>/repository/tenants/{tenantId}/userstores/{userstore_domain_name}.xml or user store configurations from the Management console for any invalid characters.

This issue can occur if there are any invalid characters present.